# Is CRTP used much? and why it is/isn't?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm thinking about [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

I find it quite useful, and it's pretty well adjustable for many tasks. But I have to admit, I don't see much of CRTP code in the wild.

Is it hard to grasp? Are virtual functions easier overall? Shouldn't it be used for 90% of cases where virtual keyword appears?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple fact is that many, if not most, C++ users can hardly grasp that `vector` is better than `malloc` and `free`, so the number who can not only appreciate but *implement* advanced template metaprogramming is not very high. This implies that even if it were good for 90% of situations, you'd see it in far less, simply because people don't know about it or how to use it.

However, virtual functions *do* have advantages, namely, virtual functions are much easier to use than the CRTP. C++ templates are notorious for being bitchy about virtually anything and everything, and the inclusion model sucks balls.

However, they [virtual functions] are distinctly slower and less powerful. For example, I right now am writing code using the CRTP, where you inherit operator overloads for use with expression templates. There's no way virtual functions could possibly make that work.

Comment: Isn't it somewhat ironical that the very language-feature that CRTP uses to avoid the use of 'virtual' is bitchy about 'virtually' anything and everything?

Answer (score 7):

[WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net) uses the CRTP. Chromium browser is a well known example of software that uses WTL, so I'd say it's used "in the wild".

About the 90%? That's definitely an overstatement. Have you ever used a container of polymorphic objects? That's a very common usage of polymorphism and you can't do that with CRTP because `Base<DerivedA>` is not the same as `Base<DerivedB>`.

Answer (score -5):

Here's reasons why it's not used more widely:

1. It's a hack
2. As a hack, it's not guaranteed you don't run into trouble when you use it. The normal OO stuff has been used by large number of projects, and found to work properly/problems are well known, the CRTP is found in only small number of projects, and no data is available
3. there is no good reason to use it - most reasons sited are just not valid
4. it can make some things more complicated

Comment: It is most assuredly not a hack. The behaviour is very well defined, and there's plenty of use of it.

Comment: Yep, whole STL is a big hack.

Comment: can you edit your answer and explain, why it is a hack?